# Llenar input precio dependiendo de la selección en Select dropdown - Laravel + Jquery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, laravel

Estoy completando el input precio, desde la selección de un `select(dropdown)` con `jquery` y el *framework laravel*.

Ambos campos vienen de una relación muchos a muchos entre Presupuesto y Prestaciones (la tabla pivote trae el precio de la prestación).

Acá una imagen del `select` y la caja de texto donde se debe llenar el precio dependiendo de la selección

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero me da un error; que precio no está definido.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Así están definidos en la vista**

```
<td>
    <select name="prestaciones[]" class="form-control" id="prestaciones">
        <option value="">-- Seleccione prestación --</option>
        @foreach ($prestaciones as $prestacion)
            <option value="{{ $prestacion->id }}"{{ $oldPrestacion == $prestacion->id ? ' selected' : '' }}>
                {{ $prestacion->presta_nombre }} 
            </option>
        @endforeach
    </select>
</td>
<td>
    <input type="number" name="precio" id="precio" placeholder="0.00" value="${{ number_format($prestacion->presta_valor, 2) }}" class="form-control total" readonly="">
</td>
```

**Acá el bloque JS**

```
$(function() {
    $('#prestaciones').on('change', function(){
        var precio = $(this).data('precio');
        $('#precio').val(precio);
        console.log(precio);
    });

});
```

Si me pueden ayudar por favor.

Gracias

Comment: Tendrías que pasarle el valor del precio a cada option cuando haces el foreach en laravel, para luego poder tomar el valor de ahí. Por ejemplo `<option value="{{ $prestacion->id }}" data-precio="{{ $prestacion->pivot->precio }}">`

Comment: Gracias @porloscerrosΨ . Si funcionó al pasarlo con data-precio. Pero solo pasa el precio al input, la primera vez que hago la seleccion. Ya cuando añado otra fila no funciona.

Comment: Veo que en la imagen que agregaste ahora, son varios selects, eso cambia las cosas. Ya no puedes usar la id del select (que debería ser único en la página) para capturar el on change. En cambio, podrías usar una clase, y buscar de alguna manera el input que corresponda a cada select. Es justamente lo que te dice Shassain en su respuesta.

Answer (score 1):

Dices que tienes: `el precio en la tabla pivote`, y si ya tienes el dato puedes acceder a él a través de `pivot`. Entonces en tu foreach tendrías lo siguiente

```
@foreach ($prestaciones as $prestacion)
    <option value="{{ $prestacion->id }}" {{ $oldPrestacion == $prestacion->id ? ' selected' : '' }} data-precio="{{$prestacion->pivot->precio}}">
        {{ $prestacion->presta_nombre }} 
    </option>
@endforeach
```

Y después solo accedes al `option:selected` para poder acceder al `data` del option seleccionado.

```
$('#prestaciones').on('change', function(){
    var precio = $("option:selected",this).data('precio');
    $('#precio').val(precio);
    console.log(precio);
});
```

Eso debería de funcionar.

**Recomendación**

Veo un `prestaciones[]`, además de que tus etiquetas están en `td`s, esto me hace pensar que tendras más de un `#prestaciones` al igual que de `#precio`; por lo cual te recomiendo cambiar dichos `ids` por `class`, para no tener problemas. Si no es el caso omite esta recomendación.

**Actualización**,

Era de suponerse que si cambias de `id` a `class` nada funcionaria, ya que para dicha acción el código es un poquito mas largo, y algo diferente.

Entonces, la lógica seria: **si cambio el valor de un `select` debe de cambiar el valor del precio en la misma fila.**

Empezamos a editar el `select`:

```
<select name="prestaciones[]" class="form-control" onchange="cambiarPrecio(this)">
    <option value="">-- Seleccione prestación --</option>
    @foreach ($prestaciones as $prestacion)
        <option value="{{ $prestacion->id }}" {{ $oldPrestacion == $prestacion->id ? ' selected' : '' }} data-precio="{{$prestacion->pivot->precio}}">
            {{ $prestacion->presta_nombre }} 
        </option>
    @endforeach
</select>
```

Donde quite el `id`, agregue la funcion `cambiarPrecio(this)`, esto para no utilizar la funcion `$('#prestaciones').on('change', function(){});`, solo porque varias veces vi un "`bug`" que al agregar un nuevo elemento a estos se les agrega los eventos de jquery. Se soluciona al momento de agregar el nuevo elemento pero esa es otra historia.

Entonces la función `cambiarPrecio(this)` quedaría así:

```
cambiarPrecio(_selft){
    var precio = $("option:selected",_selft).data('precio');
    
    //$('#precio').val(precio); esta parte sera cambiada por:
    $(_selft).parent('td').parent('tr').children("td:nth-child(2)").children("input").val(precio);
}
```

Entonces lo nuevo seria:

`.parent('td')`: el cual accede a la etiqueta padre de `select` que seria `td`.  `parent('tr')`: el cual accede a la etiqueta padre de `td` que seria `tr`.  `children("td:nth-child(2)")`: el cual accede a las etiquetas hijo de `tr`, en este caso especificamente al `td` en la posicion 2.  //en jquery se cuenta desde 1

`children("input")`: el cual accede a la etiqueta hijo de `td` de la posicion 2 que seria `input`.

Espero se entienda y que te sirva.

Comment: Hola @Shassain 
Funciona!, me pasa el precio, pero solo con la primera prestación. Cuando añado otra fila al presupuesto, ya no hace la función.
Al hacer lo de la recomendación, ya no funciona nada. Así que lo dejé tal cual por ahora (quizas es por mi poco manejo con jquery y estoy omitiendo algo)

Gracias por tu ayuda

Comment: @FranciscoMorales veo bien el código de @Shassain así como la **recomendación**; partiendo que pones como class el `id` (es decir `prestaciones` y `precio` en `class`), con el `this` en el `onchange`, tendrías que usar `var elTR= $(this).closest('tr');` ( https://api.jquery.com/closest/ ) esto sería despues del `var precio = ...;` y en vez de `$('#precio').val(precio);` sería `$('.precio', elTR).val(precio);`

Comment: Hice el cambio a class ( lo compruebo por que sigue cargando el primer precio)
Así quedó el bloque scipt.
el closest, hallo donde colocarlo.
$(function() {
                $('.prestaciones').on('change', function(){
                    var precio = $("option:selected",this).data('precio');
                    $('.precio', '.prestacion').val(precio);
                    $(this).closest('#prestacion');

                    console.log(precio);
                });

            });

Comment: @FranciscoMorales, edite la respuesta con otra posible solución.

Comment: Hola @Shassain, Hice las modificaciones, pero no lo consigo. 
Ahora al seleccionar la prestación, Me muestra estos mensajes:

Uncaught ReferenceError: cambiarPrecio is not defined
    at HTMLSelectElement.onchange

Seguido de: create:245 Uncaught ReferenceError: cambiarPrecio is not defined
    at HTMLTableRowElement.onchange

Gracias por tu comentario.